# not displaying plotly.graphs_objs in visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, plot, geo, choropleth

so this is my code

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go 
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import pandas as pd
init_notebook_mode(connected=


data = dict(type = 'choropleth',
        locations = ['AZ','CA','NY'],
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        colorscale= 'Portland',
        text= ['text1','text2','text3'],
        z=[1.0,2.0,3.0],
        colorbar = {'title':'Colorbar Title'})


layout = dict(geo = {'scope':'usa'})
choromap = go.Figure(data = [data],layout = layout)
iplot(choromap)
```

and then I run the code it is displaying some stuff in like cmd